# Store number in javascript variable, then add to it when script runs?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable I want to equal 0 when the page loads. `var number = 0;` When a button is clicked, I want to store that result inside the `number` variable and keep adding to it.

```
var number = 0;

$(document).on('click', ".math", function() {
var number = number + 8;
alert(number);
});
```

I know this seems pointless, but I am really trying to figure out how to do this. The user cant see what is happening behind the scenes, but the  number that `number` is will depend on content that is shown. It just keeps saying that number is equal to 8 and never changes. How do I allow it to increment? Thanks!

Comment: Don't re-use `var` again in your function. Just `number = number + 8;`. And don't debug with `alert`. Use the console.

Comment: `number = number + 8;` as you are trying to manipulate the value of the global `number` variable. Having keyword `var` will create another variable and the newly created variable will have function scope, not global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo. Basically you shouldn't use `var` if you want to access the global `number` variable.

```js
var number = 0;
alert(number);
$(document).on('click', ".math", function() {
  number = number + 8;
  alert(number);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="math">Click me!</button>
```